# How to make my own property attribute in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, properties, attributes

I was thinking how could I make my own property attribute, for example:

```
@property(retain,nonatomic,'myAttribute') int numberOfWheels

@property('unique',nonatomic) NSString productCode
```

but when I try to get a help from Xcode pressing command button or option button nothing happens

I was looking in this page and many others but no one ask how to make your own attribute, most of then just asking about how to use property attributes or difference between them

I dont know if its possible to make a new attribute, but if its true, could someone help me

Comment: Attribute for what?  So say how would `@property(retain,nonatomic,'myAttribute') int numberOfWheels` differ from `@property(retain,nonatomic) int numberOfWheels`

Comment: He is trying to add a new Keyword kind of thing in Obj-C.

Comment: retain int property wrong anyway

Comment: why the hell do you need that?

Comment: So if you want to call it 'myAttribute', why not @property(nonatomic) int myAttribute?

Comment: What? what are your trying to achieve?

Comment: i wanna create something like [key] in c#

i wanna create this because i making something similar to entities (c#) to objective-c 
so the 'key' attribute is to know this is a primary key for my table (which i create own my way) 

@aknew sorry i just an example, no necessary a good one 

thanks all for answer it

Comment: You might want to look into CoreData.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't waste your time trying to turn Objective-C into C#. Instead, focus on learning how Objective-C and Apple's frameworks are intended to be used; along the way, you'll discover that there are much easier ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to modify the compiler directly to add this functionality. I have no idea where you'd begin to do that, except to point you to http://llvm.org and say "good luck".